# django admin static serves in wrong url

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I have a weird issue -  my dev server trying to serve admin static by using a wrong url.

using django 1.6

my main urlconf

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^$', include('dash.urls')),
   )


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

and settings are like

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
locale = lambda path: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, path)
STATIC_URL = "static/"
MEDIA_URL = "media/"
STATIC_ROOT = locale("static")
MEDIA_ROOT = locale("media")
```

apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

the weird thing is that my custom apps serves static normaly by urls like
localhost:8000/static/css/blah

but the admin one uses

[24/Nov/2013 18:47:41] "GET /admin/static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4316

Guys, seriously, what is the origin of prefix /admin/static? 0_o
I am nat using deprecated stuff like ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX.

Base admin template uses
{% static "admin/css/base.css" %} tag, which code is

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

if 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
else:
    from django.templatetags.static import static

static = register.simple_tag(static)
```

which seams ok;

I am confused, help me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `STATIC_URL` does not start with a slash so it is treated as a relative URL. Hence you'll get:

- `/admin/` (which is where the admin is),
- `static/` (your `STATIC_URL`), and
- `admin/css/base.css` (which is where the file is).

In other words, that's why it's requesting `/admin/static/admin/css/base.css`.

You should add a slash to your `STATIC_URL` to make it request `/static/admin/css/base.css`.